ArcGIS intersect lines except for identical geometry with themselves
ArcGIS Pro 3.2.1.
I have streets that I'd like to turn into intersections. On occasion, there are duplicate street lines (same geometry) that have different names (using an alias table is currently not an option). My current process in Model Builder is:

Intersect Tool - intersect line FC on itself to create point feature class, multi-points at intersections
Multipart to Singlepart to separate features
Join Features GeoAnalytics tool, FC from step 2 as the target feature, original streets as the join feature, Join Condition $join["street"] != $target["street"]. One to many explodes the points, one new point feature per unique street combination.
Export, filter out where street 1 and street 2 have the same name
Calculate Field new intersection field, Street 1 / Street 2
Delete identical based on the new intersect field

The issue is that those lines with identical geometries (but different names) will intersect with each other. How can I prevent this from happening?
e.g. in the screenshot below, the left street has 3 names. So I want Street 5 / Street 2 + Street 3 / Street 2 + Street 4 / Street 2 in my results, but not Street 5 / Street 4  or Street 3 / Street 4 or Street 5 / Street 3 since they're the same street with different names.


Could you run the intersection, allow all variants to generate, then simply select up the ones you don't want and delete them out?

That could work. I'd need another process then to separate the dup geometries into their own table, then a flag check if both street 1 and street 2 exist in that new table. I was hoping there was some sort of special tool or setting that could this
